# Can 'its' appear before a thing mentioned?

Tags: word-order, possessive-pronouns

Can 'its' appear before a thing mentioned?

Example ('its'='the software'):

> We think that after **its** upgrade, the software will be popular in places that need privacy.

(I know that this sentence can be written in better way, example only to understand the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It" doesn't always have to be previously mentioned, but it does have to be clear or obvious what it refers to. For example, "it's a nice day" is a common exclamation. "It" refers to the present day, and it would be obvious what you meant. "It" could also be something that both parties can *see*, so there would be no need to verbally state what you were referring to. For example, if you were both looking at a piece of art, and you said "it's impressive, isn't it?", it would be obvious you meant the art.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it definitely can. It's common to write this way. And I think your example reads nicer the way you wrote it, compared to putting "the software's upgrade" first.